# In react native, complete todo completes all todo

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

Hello dear stackoverflow users. I'm learning React native but there is something I can't do. I am developing a todo application where I keep a state called completeTodo to mark the todo as done and when my todo component is onpress I reverse it but it affects all todo what can I do to solve it?

I used nativewind for css in this project. nativewind react is the same tailwindcss developed for native.

My app.js file

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useState, React } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Platform, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { useColorScheme } from "nativewind";
import Task from './components/Task.js'
import KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView.js';
import Pressable from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Pressable/Pressable.js';

export default function App() {
  const { colorScheme, toggleColorScheme } = useColorScheme();
  const [task, setTask] = useState()
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false)
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([])

  const addTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss()
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
    setTask(null)
  }
 
  const deleteTask = () => {

  }
  const updateTask = () => {

  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-gray-500/20 flex-1 dark:bg-black/90 overflow-auto">
      <View className="w-full sticky top-0 left-0 flex items-end px-5 h-10 justify-center">
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleColorScheme}>
          <Text className="dark:text-white">
            {colorScheme === "dark" ? ` ${colorScheme}` : ` ${colorScheme}`}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View className="mt-5 px-5">
        {
          taskItems.map((item, index) => {
            return <Task key={index} setIsCompleted={setIsCompleted} isCompleted={isCompleted} text={item} />

          })
        }
      </View>

      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.addTask}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}>
        <View>
          <TextInput onChangeText={text => setTask(text)}
            value={task}
            className="relative border px-5 py-5 border-gray-500/20 focus:border-gray-500 rounded-xl dark:text-white pr-16"
            placeholder='Lets! Tell me something to do' placeholderTextColor={colorScheme === "dark" ? "#fff" : "#000"}></TextInput>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => addTask()}
            className="px-5 py-2 absolute right-0 top-0 h-full justify-center items-center">
            <Text>Add</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView >
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  addTask: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 40,
    width: "100%",
    paddingHorizontal: 20
  }
})
```

my task component :

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const Task = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => props.setIsCompleted(!props.isCompleted)}
            className={`mt-5 dark:bg-white p-5 rounded-xl ${props.isCompleted ? 'bg-pink-200' : 'bg-white'}`}>
            <Text className={`${props.isCompleted ? 'text-white line-through' : ''}`}>
                {props.text}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    )
}

export default Task;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single boolean state to handle a state of an array of individual components. Hence, if you set this state to a different value, all of your `Task` components will be marked as completed.

This can be easily fixed. Instead of defining the state `isCompleted` in the parent component and passing it as prop to `Task`, you can just define this state inside `Task`. This will create an individual state for each of your `Task` components.

```js
const Task = (props) => {

    const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => setIsCompleted(prev => !prev)}
            className={`mt-5 dark:bg-white p-5 rounded-xl ${isCompleted ? 'bg-pink-200' : 'bg-white'}`}>
            <Text className={`${isCompleted ? 'text-white line-through' : ''}`}>
                {props.text}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    )
}
```

You can remove the `isCompleted` state from your parent component and just create a `Task` without passing anything.

```js
 <View className="mt-5 px-5">
        {
          taskItems.map((item, index) => {
            return <Task key={index} text={item} />
          })
        }
      </View>
```